# How to make OpenRazer to work with Razer Ornata V2 Chroma on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: keyboard

What has been done so far:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrazer/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openrazer-meta
sudo gpasswd -a $USER plugdev
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install polychromatic
```

All seems to install fine, the daemon appears on the taskbar but gives "no device found", however: the device IS recognized being present when opening the Polychromatic: "a Razer product is connected to your computer, but the daemon didn't detect it"

Ornata Chroma appears to be on the supported devices list: Razer Ornata Chroma 1532:021E   and Razer Ornata 1532:021F

What more to do now? This is a "V2", so could it be that it is actually NOT yet supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The V2 is not supported yet on the stable branch.It has been added on the master branch and will probably be available in the next release.